# Permisos de Localización no me Funcionan en el teléfono, si en el emulador!

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, geolocalización, gps

Tengo esta situación peculiar.

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que llama la locación del celular.

En el emulador android oreo funciona muy bien, la primera vez pide el permiso y funciona correctamente. Pero si la corro en el celular ya sea en xamarin player o en el celular como tal. No me da los permisos de localización.

He buscado mucho y parece algo que es muy nuevo, algún cambio en la forma en que se piden los permisos imagino yo.

**Este es mi MainActivity.cs**

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Plugin.Permissions;
using Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;

namespace Geo.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "Geo", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            LoadApplication(new App());


        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Plugin.Permissions.PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

    }
}
```

**Este es mi assemblyInfo.cs**

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Android.App;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Geo.Android")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Geo.Android")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2014")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]

// Add some common permissions, these can be removed if not needed
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.location", Required = false)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.location.gps", Required = false)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.location.network", Required = false)]
```

**Y este mi Mainpage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.Geolocator;
using Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions;
using Plugin.Permissions;

namespace Geo
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {


        const int RequestLocationId = 0;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private async void TestB_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(new[] { Permission.Location });
                status = results[Permission.Location];

                if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    string msg = "No tenemos acceso a tu posicion";
                   await DisplayAlert("Alerta", msg, "ok");
                    return;
                }
            }




            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 20;

            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync();

            Lat.Text = "Latitude: " + position.Latitude.ToString();
            Long.Text = "Longitude: " + position.Longitude.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola! No sé mucho de desarrollo en Xamarin, sin embargo he desarrollado con Android Studio. A partir de Android Marshmallow los permisos se tienen que pedir Durante el Runtime de tu aplicación. Quizá esta respuesta de SO te pueda servir https://stackoverflow.com/a/40051927/7023800

Comment: ActivityCompat no existe en Xamarin Forms